# Python & Pandas: Create a 3d histogram from 2 columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In my data frame, I have `df['incre']` and `df['incre_reverse']`, the data is like this (the last 2 column):
[image]

Now, I want plot a 3d histogram (or 2d with color), the `X, Y` would be the `df['incre']`, `df['incre_reverse']`, the `Z` is the number of occurance.

How can I do that?

I find a example here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html

But all I can produce is this:

[image]

For scatter plot:

```
X = df['incre']
Y = df['incre_reverse']
plt.scatter(X, Y, alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

Is there any suggestion for make the scatter plot more clear? Or what would be a good way to plot the 3d histogram?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some values that are very common.

To make things look more ballanced consider plotting the histogram using the log of your values with NumPy `np.log()`.

Comment: But I have negative value, how can I deal with that?

Comment: The `np.log()` is used on the hist values or the counts of your raw binned values. So even though the raw data might be negative the counts will at least be greater than or equal to zero. One useful trick is to scale you counts with `np.log(1 + count)`, which will cater for 0 count values. 0 count will get mapped to 0 and larger numbers are more visually comparable with smaller ones.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need more bins.
At the moment you have:

```
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=10, range=[[-60, 60], [-60, 60]])
```

Have you tried adding more bins ?